# Spring boot returns 404 on login.jsp

Tags: java, jsp, spring-boot, http-status-code-404, http-status-code-302

The login.jsp is located under /WEB-INF/views/ and the URL https://myprog.at.something:8080/login returns the "404 not found-message". 
If I enter another URL, as for example https://myprog.at.something:8080/logout, I got a "302 found" message.

Console and debug mode shows no error. It is strange that this happens only on my computer, when a colleague is running the same spring boot application, it is starting without any problems on the login page.

**Part of SpringConfigRootApplication.java**

```
@Bean
public InternalResourceViewResolver getInternalResourceViewResolver() {
    final InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
    resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
    resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
    resolver.setRequestContextAttribute("requestContext");
    resolver.setExposeContextBeansAsAttributes(true);
    return resolver;
}

@Override
public void addViewControllers(final ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
    registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
}
```

**Part of SpringConfigSecurity.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringConfigSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;


    @Override
    @Autowired
    public void configure(final AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(NoOpPasswordEncoder.getInstance());
    }


    @Override
    public void configure(final WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**", "/console/**", "/ping");
    }


    @Override
    protected void configure(final HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .csrf().disable()                   
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
                .loginProcessingUrl("/authcheck")
                .usernameParameter("username")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .failureUrl("/login?failed=true")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
                .logout().logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }
}
```

**Part of application.properties**

```
server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false
spring.view.prefix: /WEB-INF/views/
spring.view.suffix: .jsp
```

Comment: try this link - https://myprog.at.something:8080/views/login

Comment: No, sorry, didn't change anything.